# How to keep a Heroku dyno alive for a certain time interval?

Tags: node.js, heroku, hubot, slack-api

Since the start of June 2015, free Heroku dynos have had to sleep for six hours in a 24-hour interval, thus rendering things like New Relic useless.

I've got a Slack bot running on a free Heroku dyno that we use around the office for parsing Smartsheet documents and searching Google News. I was wondering if there's any way to keep this dyno alive for a certain time interval? Say, 7am-11pm every day? It'd leave the six-hour interval in there, while still keeping it active for business hours. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping#quota), it looks like you can scale your app down to zero - in which case it won't be active.

So maybe do a `heroku dyno:scale web=0` (if you just have a web dyno) during the periods you don't want activity.  Or automate it maybe via some call to their API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use heroku scheduler to wake a sleeping dyno at a specified time. Then to keep it alive for x hours you can have the app make a get request to your site every half-hour for x hours. Please do not abuse this, as the tragedy of the Commons could ruin the free tier for all of us. Personally i use this technique for an app I need alive 1 hour per day.